# Change method using db helper into AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a method within my main thread which gets values from my db helper class and returns a string, and also assigns another string to a texview.

But I would like to perform the operation in the background and publish the results on my main UI thread. Reading through the documentation I am struggling to know how to create an AsyncTask, or at least structure it to achieve this without compromising the function. My current main thread method:

```
     public String showNextRandomQuestion3() {

            SQLDatabaseHelper db = new SQLDatabaseHelper(this);

            //get the data from the database
            List<List<String>> listList = db.getAllAnswersByQuestion1();

            //Get the question/text/answer Strings
            List<String> questionStrings = listList.get(0); //question Strings
            List<String> answerSetIds = listList.get(1);

            //Generate random index
            Random r = new Random();
            int rand = Math.abs((r.nextInt() % questionStrings.size()));

            //get answer description for randomly selected question
            String questionString = questionStrings.get(rand);  
            String answerSetId = answerSetIds.get(rand);

            String regex = "\\[|\\]";
            questionString = questionString.replaceAll(regex, "");
            answerSetId = answerSetId.replaceAll(regex, "");

            questionView.setText(questionString);

            return answerSetId;
            }
```

Any help on the approach to creating AsyncTask for this would be much appreciated.

---

Upon making suggested changes - I get the following exception:

```
05-23 21:23:44.510: D/AndroidRuntime(4598): Shutting down VM
05-23 21:23:44.510: W/dalvikvm(4598): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415aad88)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598): Process: com.example.quizapp, PID: 4598
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598): java.util.NoSuchElementException
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:208)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at com.example.quizapp.MainActivity.showNextAnswers(MainActivity.java:431)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at com.example.quizapp.MainActivity$7.onClick(MainActivity.java:339)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4569)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18553)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
05-23 21:23:44.520: E/AndroidRuntime(4598):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-23 21:23:46.460: I/Process(4598): Sending signal. PID: 4598 SIG: 9
05-23 21:23:46.770: D/dalvikvm(5085): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 50K, 74% free 3071K/11416K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
05-23 21:23:46.790: I/dalvikvm-heap(5085): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.905MB for 15422416-byte allocation
05-23 21:23:46.980: I/Adreno-EGL(5085): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4
```

---

Upoin clicking a button I need this method to be called along with several other methods, which is why I didn't put the onClick within the AsyncTask:

```
        NextQuestionButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){;
                @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {  

//                  showNextAnswers();                      showNextQuestion();
                    showNextRandomQuestion3();
                    countQuestions();

                }});
```

Comment: Why do you want to perform DB operation in AsyncTask? Is it doing to much work on main Thread?

Comment: Yes exactly that. I'm getting exceptions for doing too much on main thread.

Answer (score 0):

May Be Below code will work for you.

```
//Define This in Activity Class;
private String answerId;

private class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            SQLDatabaseHelper db = new SQLDatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);

            //get the data from the database
            List<List<String>> listList = db.getAllAnswersByQuestion1();

            //Get the question/text/answer Strings
            List<String> questionStrings = listList.get(0); //question Strings
            List<String> answerSetIds = listList.get(1);

            //Generate random index
            Random r = new Random();
            int rand = Math.abs((r.nextInt() % questionStrings.size()));

            //get answer description for randomly selected question
            String questionString = questionStrings.get(rand);  
            String answerSetId = answerSetIds.get(rand);

            String regex = "\\[|\\]";
            answerId = answerSetId.replaceAll(regex, "");
            return mQuestionString = questionString.replaceAll(regex, "");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         questionView.setText(questionString);  
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks - great help. At the moment I am still getting an exception - W/dalvikvm(4598): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415aad88). Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @jrgart  can you show me the stacktrace? or can point me on which line you are getting exception?

Comment: Have added it to my question above now

Comment: Check the line MainActivity.java:339 for exception. may be you have used wrong logic for iterating collection.

Comment: Cheers - it was another method I was calling which I hadn't changed to use the 'answerId' string yet. I have one more question for now - I have posted it above also - how would I call the AsyncTask from onClick

Comment: To Execute AsyncTask you can use "new Task.execute()".

Comment: Sorry its "new Task().execute()"